# Element A is positioned over Element B. Anyway, when hovering over Element A, make the page appear that Element B is still being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have table rows where, when hovered over, the row appears transparent (by changing the opacity level). I need text to appear over the center of the row when row is hovered. During the hover event, I change the position of a span tag to be over the row**. That works fine. The problem is that if the user hovers over the new text, the leave hover event kicks off for the row, and I get a flashing kind of effect.

Is there anyway, when the new text is hovered over, to have the leave hover event for the row to not get kicked off?

** I did it this way because, if I included the text as a tag inside the row itself, the text would take the same opacity level as the rest of the row. I couldn't find a way to get this to stop happening.

```
<script>
  for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
     var name="#row" + i;

     $(name).hover(function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", 0.2);
        $("#text").show();
        $("#text").css("top", -20);
     }, function() {
        $(this).css("opacity", 1.0);
        $("#text").hide();
     });
  }

</script>

<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td>Stuff</td>
    <td>Stuff2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<span id="text" style="display: none;">Click here</span>
```

Comment: you need to show us some code.

Comment: Are you using javascript to display the span?

Comment: What browser is this occurring in, I am not getting it for Firefox

Comment: I've been testing in Chrome. I tried Firefox just now. I can still get the same issue to happen there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var span = $('#text');
  $('tr').hover(function () {
      $('td',this).css('opacity','0.2');
      $(this).append(span);
      span.show();
  },function () {
      $('td',this).css('opacity','1');
      span.remove();
  })
})
```

But you may need to make a few changes in your CSS too; check in the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/m2J8R/12/**

If I'm correct to avoid that flashing effect on your function change this selector:

```
$(this).css("opacity", 0.2);
```

For this

```
$('td',this).css("opacity", 0.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it CSS only, you must place your text inside the row.

And then, to avoid hiding it with the row, use

```
visibility: hidden;
```

to the row (instead of `opacity: 0`), and

```
visibility: visible;
```

to the visible element.

But to avoid blinking, you should make that element to expand to all row.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BLAqm/)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but I still need the row to be partially visible, so I'm setting the opacity to 0.2 instead of just 0.